# LDAP (slapd) ACL issue - can add but not modify entries

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I have an issue with the ACL configuration of an LDAP server (slapd). The following ACL entry is active as the first rule that applies:

```
{0}to dn.subtree="ou=some,ou=where,ou=beneath,dc=the,dc=rain,dc=bow"  attrs=entry,children by users write
```

Now the strange thing that happens is that given that rule I can add an entry to the respective DN but if I want to modify it with the very same user, then I get

> 0x32 (LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS)

Can someone give me a hint what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow the modification of the whole entry, you need to remove the `attrs=` option completely.
I think your'e misunderstanding what the `attrs=entry` does. It doesnt let you modify the whole entry. The `entry` attribute only grants permission to the entry itself (**not its attribtes**), which basically only allows you to delete it. The `children` attribute is what is letting you create new children under that entry. But as soon as the child is created, you cant modify it because it falls under the `dn.subtree` match, and your ACL forbids modification of anything other than deleting the entry and creating children.

From http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html:

> There are two special pseudo attributes entry and children. To read
>   (and hence return) a target entry, the subject must have read access
>   to the target's entry attribute. To perform a search, the subject must
>   have search access to the search base's entry attribute. To add or
>   delete an entry, the subject must have write access to the entry's
>   entry attribute AND must have write access to the entry's parent's
>   children attribute. To rename an entry, the subject must have write
>   access to entry's entry attribute AND have write access to both the
>   old parent's and new parent's children attributes. The complete
>   examples at the end of this section should help clear things up.

As mentioned, the solution is to remove the `attrs` option. This makes the ACL default to everything, so when you specify `write`, it lets you write to everything on that entry.